# require Bootstrap with webpack angular 1.x project shows

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, npm, webpack

I have installed npm bootstrap with my webpack based angular 1.x project. But when i require("bootstrap") after require("jquery") i am getting module not found error.   Saying

[$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module adminsuite due to: Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'adminsuite' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the correct spell

Can anyone explain how to use it . Also what do i doe if i need less support for bootstrap.

I haven't done any changes to the webpack.congif.js file for the bootstrap implementation.

### webpack config.

```
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  context: __dirname + '/app',
  entry:"./index.js",
  output:{
    path:__dirname + "/app",
    filename:"bundle.js"
  },
  watch:true
```

}

### index.js

```
var angular = require('angular');
var $ = require('jquery');
window.jQuery = $;
var bootstrap = require('bootstrap');
var ngModule = angular.module('adminsuite');
alert("helloo");
```

### index.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
        <meta charset ="utf-8">
        <title>OPG Adminsuite</title>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="adminsuite">
    <h1>Adminsuite</h1>


    <div class="container">
        <form class="login-form">
            <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="username">Username</label>
                  <input type="username" class="form-control" id="username" placeholder="Userame">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="password">Password</label>
                  <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Password">
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Login</button>
        </form>


    </div>


    <script src="bundle.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Can anyone help me out in this.

Answer (score 2):

Your error has nothing to do with Bootstrap - calling `angular.module` with one argument *gets* an existing module rather than creating one. You need to pass an array (containing the names of any dependencies your module has) as the second argument.

```
// Wrong
var ngModule = angular.module('adminsuite');

// Right
var ngModule = angular.module('adminsuite', []);
```